# Java EOSL for each version

Tags: java

What are the official dates when the different versions of Java (JDK 1.3, JDK 1.4, Java 5,...) have reached it's end of service life (EOSL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend:

[Java SE EOL policy](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/eol.policy.html)